# Why there is long pause between Js file download and ajax request it consist?

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, optimization, firebug

I am trying to optimize the load timing of the Codeigniter based enterprise application. My basic structure is to load one basic html page which consist of sidebar, topmenu and basic skeleton. Also I load 5 js files which has some ajax requests. This ajax request brings the grid data as needed.

Now the issue is while I was optimizing the time to finish the first complete paint, I noticed that there is a huge gap between one of my major ajax request start and the time to download the JavaScript file which has initialized that request as you can see in the below screenshot.

Also Note that I have initiated the ajax function  as first block of the code as soon as possible once all JS files are loaded.

[image]

Comment: Maybe because javascript is compiled language and the compilation step takes that amount of time? (Note that compiler must run through the whole code before anything is executed) I am guessing here.

Comment: I guessed the same but why such a long time to compile decision to  just one ajax call?

Comment: Well, I am no expert on compilers but I know that compilation of javascript is actually more complicated than of most other languages and compiler usually runs through the code several times to make reasonable optimizations and still be fast (that number is vendor dependent). So I would say that it is not so simple as to say - just one ajax call -, but then again, this is a question more suited for browser (javascript engine) developers